# How do I disable the pasting of tables in tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, paste

I'm using on tinyMCE on my site, and don't want users to be able to use tables. I disabled the  table plugin, but they can still paste tables.

How do I disable them completely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) configuration section, and remove the table, tablehead, td etc. elements from the default valid elements string.